# Netbeans 17 - How to stop background scanning of projects?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

Netbeans has been very annoying, I used Netbeans 8 with Maven projects before and it didn't have this issue, but since I had to update to java 11 and use Netbeans 17, this problem appears. It is completely unusable IDE to me anymore.

When I opened Netbeans, it has a popup saying "Background scanning of projects" and it has been taking more than 10 minutes to run???

I don't have Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files (Enable auto-scanning of sources) checkbox enabled.

I noticed that Netbeans is trying to scan my **build directory** as well which I don't understand why it wants to do that.

Comment: I don't have that problem with NetBeans 17, but someone else did - see Bug Report [NetBeans 17 Background Scanning of Projects doesn't ever complete, without throwing an Unexpected Exception #5793](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/5793). Restart NetBeans and let the scanning run for 5 or 10 minutes, then check the NetBeans log file (**View > IDE Log**). Update your question if there is anything relevant in that log's most recent entries.

Comment: Another thing to try is to close some of your projects, and then restart NetBeans to see if the problem is diminished, or goes away completely. If the problem persists, repeat the cycle of closing a few more projects and then restarting NetBeans. That approach is tedious, but it may allow you to determine whether the files of some specific project(s) provoke the problem. You could also try playing with the _Ignored Files Pattern_ field, which is on the same screen as the _Enable auto-scanning of sources_ checkbox.

Comment: @skomisa thank you for your tips, I will check them soon. It was my favorite IDE, but with this issue, I had to change to IntellJ.